# Find $r_2$ such that $U_1(x, r_2) \subset U_2(x, \varepsilon)$ to show two metrics are equivalent.

Tags: metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

> Consider $X := (0, 1]$ and the metrics $d_1(x, y) := \left| \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} \right|$ and $d_2(x, y) = |x - y|$ and show they are topologically equivalent, i.e. for all $x \in X$
>   $$
> \forall \varepsilon > 0 \ 
> \exists r > 0:
> U_1(x,r) \subset U_2(x,\varepsilon)
> \quad\text{and} \quad
> U_2(x,r) \subset U_1(x,\varepsilon),
> $$
>   where $U_i(x,r) := \{ y \in X: d_i(x,y) < r\}$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$.

Here's my attempt:
Let $x \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $r_1 := \varepsilon$.
For $x,y \in X$ we have $x y \in X$ and therefore
\begin{equation*}
d_1(x,y)
= \frac{|x - y|}{xy}
\le d_2(x,y).
\end{equation*}
**Now I have to choose $r_2$ such that $U_1(x,r_2) \subset U_2(x, \varepsilon)$ but I can't find how to do it.** I guess it has to depend on $x$ and not only on $\varepsilon$.
Choosing $r := \min(r_1, r_2)$ would finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a closed subset of $(X,d_1)$ and $c$ a limit point for the set $C$ with respect to $(X,d_2)$. Then you have that there exists a sequence $c_n\to c$ that lies on $C$ and you have that

$d_1(c,c_n)=|\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{c_n}|=d_2(\frac{1}{c},\frac{1}{c_n})=|\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{c}|=0$

Because $\frac{1}{x}$ is a continuos function with respect to $(X,d_2)$

So $c$ is a limit point for $C$ with respect $d_1$ but $C$ is $d_1-$ closed so $c\in C$.

This means that $C$ is closed in $d_2$, that means $\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$.

In a similar way you can prove that $\tau_2\subseteq \tau_1$.

Thus $\tau_1=\tau_2$ so the two metrics are equivalent.

Comment: Please, I just want to know the right $r$...